# How to define a Label class in MyEclipse?

Tags: java, database, swing, label, resultset

I have set many lables and I want them to show the data from database.But it shows"com.myql.jdbc.JDBC4ResultSet"

The sql sentences' results are double

And there is the code as follows

```
private void initData() {
        initCondition("select sum(initAmount) from account", lblInit);
        initCondition("select sum(amount) from detail where directionid = 1", lblIncome);
        initCondition("select sum(amount) from detail where directionid = 2", lblOutcome);
        lblAsset.setText("as");
    }
```

//It's my definition about the label class.

```
private void initCondition(String sql, JLabel jLabel) {
    try {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user,
                password);
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        jLabel.setText(resultSet.toString());
        resultSet.close();
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The result of sql is a double number. I think the resultset needn't loop.

Are you saying the result set contains just one column of data in one row?  In that case, maybe something along the lines of..

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
resultSet.first();
jLabel.setText("" + resultSet.getDouble(1));
```

Comment: The result of sql is a double number. I think the resultset needn't loop.